# Redirect conflict with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I needed to redirect all pages starting with CAPS to lowercase which works fine;

```
RewriteRule ^(?=.*?[A-Z])(apartments/.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

This redirects well but the issue is when i try to redirect succeeding directories for instance `apartments/London/South => apartments/london`

It redirects all to lowercase instead to the new direction.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I have figured it out:

RewriteRule ^/apartments(/.*|)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]

Then for subfolder redirects:
RewriteRule ^apartments/London/(.*)+$ /apartments/london [R=301,L]

Comment: Have you solved your stated problem?

Comment: I thought the solution I pasted had worked but it didn't. So I havn't got a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule worked on my apache but it could be because of different versions. Can you try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(apartments(?:/.*|))$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test this in a different browser or clear your browser cache.

Comment: This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: I have tried the new solution in different browsers and get same out: Request-URI Too Large

The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.

Comment: What is your Apache version and what is your full URL? Is it `/apartments/London/South` ?

Comment: apache 2.2.. I have different sub directories under apartment. The only one I want to be changed to lowercase is the succeeding sub directory. apartment/London will be redirected to apartment/london and apartment/London/South will be apartment/london/South/. I have different areas e.g London, New York etc